# Open server. Подключение картинки через css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, openserver

Я подключаю картинку через css  background: url(Site/img/Gare.jpg);
А происходит ошибка GET http://site/css/Site/img/Gare.jpg 404 (Not Found)
В ошибке неправильный путь. Как быть?

Comment: Очевидно неправильный поменяйте не `url(/img/Gare.jpg);`

Comment: `//` перед путем добавте -> `url(//Site/img/Gare.jpg);`